# Express change session every request

Tags: node.js, session, redis

I have a function to login

```
app.post('/doLogin', function(req,res){
        db.users.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {
            if( err ) {
                console.log("Login fail");
            } 
            else if (user != null) {
                if (req.body.password == user.password) {
                    req.session.user_role = "user";
                    req.session.save();
            } else {
                req.session.user_role = "null";
                console.log("Wrong login");
            }
        }
        res.send({redirect: "/"});
    });

});
```

This function is used to save a variable into session `req.session.user_role = "user";`
But when the new request to check user logged in or not

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    redis.get('sess:' + req.session.id, function(err, result){
        console.log("Get session: " + util.inspect(JSON.parse(result),{ showHidden: true, depth: null }));
    });
    if ((req.session.user_role == "user")) {
          console.log("Logged in");
    } else {
        console.log("Logged out");
    }
});
```

Then return always is "Logged out", because the session is changed. I use Redis to store session, I think it is Redis fault because when I stop using Redis, it's OK
Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do things is to always let Express deal with it, if it can.

https://flaviocopes.com/express-sessions/ ( Updated Session tutorial although links should not be considered answers )

There's a link that can show you how to set up redis for sessions in Express.  You shouldn't have to even query redis yourself when dealing with sessions, that's a job for middleware in node.

Comment: And my newbishness strikes again.   How do you have your session middleware set up?  Please post that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I set cookie: {secure: false} and it's ok now. But I really want to know the strategy if I want to set {secure: true}

Comment: The docs on the {secure: true} are thin, to say the least, but it might have something to do with trusting the reverse proxy if your app is behind one.  'might' is the key word.

Comment: This is resolved and fairly old now, but it has come up in multiple of my searches today, so I will add this for those in the same situation: on Windows, there is currently no available installation of Redis that works properly with express-session. The easiest workaround I found was to enable [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), install Ubuntu in the command prompt, install Redis, and host from the subsystem.

Answer (score 19):

**Express-session** uses the cookie to set or get the session id from the client

as stated on the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

> Please note that secure: true is a recommended option. However, it
>   requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure
>   cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the
>   cookie will not be set.

**Remember the below points:**

- If you are not hosting on HTTPS connection cookie secure flag should
  be set to false.
- If the you are using a proxy thats hosted on the HTTPS you should set
  trust proxy to 1. Refer the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

---

### Below option will resolve the issue of session ID reset for every request

```
cookie: { secure: false }
```

for example:

```
app.use(session({
  // your settings
  cookie: { secure: false }
}))
```

---

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time

Comment: Documentation also states that the default value for cookie is `{ path: '/', httpOnly: true, secure: false, maxAge: null }`. Is the documentation wrong at this point or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are some asynchronous errors in your code. Every time you have the asynchronous operation(like a callback), you should make sure that your rest code is executed after the callback function, so you may put the code into the callback function. Just like this:

```
db.users.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {
  if( err ) {
    console.log("Login fail");
  } 
  else if (user != null) {
    if (req.body.password == user.password) {
      req.session.user_role = "user";
      req.session.save();
      res.send({redirect: "/"});
    } else {
      req.session.user_role = "null";
      console.log("Wrong login");
      res.send({redirect: "/"});
    }
  }
});
```

And the `app.get` should look like:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  redis.get('sess:' + req.session.id, function(err, result){
    console.log("Get session: " + util.inspect(JSON.parse(result),{ showHidden: true, depth: null }));
    if ((req.session.user_role == "user")) {
      console.log("Logged in");
    } else {
      console.log("Logged out");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If {secure:true} is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the cookie will not be set. So, each request will create a new session.

Answer (score 0):

All answers so far are helpful but don't directly solve the issue with using secure:true.

In order to use secure:true you must have support for https for secure cookies. Additionally you must use withCredentials for cross-site access control. withCrendentials:true has no impact on same-site request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Majority of libraries support this parameter in their configurations such as angular and dropzone.