# req.session.id is different for each request in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, passport.js, express-session

I am using passportjs for my login module. In order to save cookies I have used express-session library, but for each request it generates a new session id, and in the client side connect.sid is not set.

Note: My react app is running on digital ocean server and my node app is running on AWS server.

API call in my react app:

```
axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true }).then((response) => {
  console.log('login:', response.data)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log('error:', e)
})
```

session setting in my node app:

```
  router.use(cookieParser())
  router.use(
    session({
      secret: 'keyboard cat',
      cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    })
  )
  router.use(passport.initialize())
  router.use(passport.session())
```

Comment: Show us the login code and also Passport configuration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814940/express-change-session-every-request 

https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/374
 refere this for similar issue

Comment: Because you use `axios` - a http client tool, to takes request, `express-session` only effect if you use browser to take the request.

Comment: Thanks for every one, My browser has blocked the cookies from third party url, So  react could not set connect.sid,  Now i enabled it. It's working fine now.