# nodejs, expressjs ) sessionID is regenerated on every request even secure is set to false

Tags: node.js, express, session

I know there are already some questions with same problems. But none of them solved my issue.
I use reactJS as my frontend code and expressJS as my server code.
My problem is, each time express gets request, it regenerates a different sessionID.

As the solution I found here, [Express change session every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814940/express-change-session-every-request/32457268), that secure must be set to false if you want to prevent sessionID from resetting for every request.

The code below is my session setting in app.js

```
 app.use(
  session({
   resave:false,
   saveUninitialized:false,
   secret:process.env.redis_secret_key,
   cookie:{
     maxAge:3600,
     httpOnly:true,
     /**
      * for production code:
      * secure:true
     */
     secure:false
   },
   store:new RedisClient({createdClientRedis})
 })
);
```

As you see, secure is set to false, but!
the code which I used to set cookie and redis.get shows me different sessionID.

code of cookie.js

```
const express = require('express');
 module.exports={
   setCookie:function(res,req,id){
   res.cookie('user',req.sessionID);
 },
 removeCookie:function(res){
   res.clearCookie('user',{path:'/'});
 }
}
```

result:
[image]

redis code:

```
    getRedis:function(req){
    console.log("get redis "+req.sessionID);
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        //some redis.get code
    })
},
```

result:
[image]

Of course, getRedis function generates different sessionID for every request too.. and I cannot get value from redis database.

And the react code which I use to send a fetch request to server already has credentials setting.

```
export function chatRoomFetch(type,requestBody){
return fetch(`//localhost:8000/chat/${type}`,{
        method:'POST',
        credentials:'include',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    }).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    });
 };
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my entire express.js app.js code

```
//main javascript file for nodejs. server

const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const cors =require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const chatRouter = require('./router/chatRouter.js');
const authRouter = require('./router/authRouter.js');
const redis = require ('./redis/redis');
const { RedisClient } = require('redis');
const redisStore= require('connect-redis')(session);
require('dotenv').config();
//cors setting
app.use(cors({
  origin:'http://localhost:8081',
  credentials:true
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
//redis
const createdClientRedis = redis.createRedisClient();
app.use(
  session({
    resave:false,
    name:'user',
    saveUninitialized:false,
    secret:process.env.redis_secret_key,
    cookie:{
      maxAge:3600, 
      httpOnly:true,
      /**
       * for production code:
       * secure:true
       */
      secure:false
    },
    store:new RedisClient({createdClientRedis})
  })    
);

//Routers
app.use('/chat',chatRouter);
app.use('/auth',authRouter);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```

Comment: Is localhost:8000 the same origin that the web page the script is in is from?  Or is your `fetch()` request a cross origin request?

Comment: Also, it's unclear why you're trying to put your own sessionID into a cookie.  That's what express-session does for you automtically.

Comment: @jfriend00 cross origin request, check my uploaded app.js code

Comment: @jfriend00 I guess I need to set cookie manually when user signs in

Comment: Well, first you have to debug what is happening with the cross origin cookie.  In the Chrome debugger (network tab), you can see both the response from the first request (that should contain the session cookie you can see) and you can see the next request to see if the session cookie is being sent back or not?  My guess is you have a cross origin cookie issue.

Comment: Then, if you're using express-session, the general idea is you don't need to set a separate cookie for login.  Instead, you put some login state into the server-side session and when the next request comes in (with the prior session cookie attached), the express-session code reunites the new request with the prior server-side session data (which will indicate logged in state) and you use it that way - without setting a separate login cookie that can be forged.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for your comments, now here is it 3AM so I will try that when I wake up

Comment: @jfriend00 but I have a question, whenever I try to run my getRedis function, I get different req.sessionID in console. What is the reason of that? credentials is set to include and secure is set to false.. I don't understand why it happens so.

Comment: I already explained how you can track the session cookie in the browser and see if your client is receiving the session cookie and then sending it back on the next one.  I have no idea what you're doing with the `getRedis()` function to know anything about that.  `req.session` will be your session object in Express.